# Connection to Artemis via Stomp breaks when trying to read big messages using SSL

Tags: php, ssl, stomp, activemq-artemis

My code is fairly simple. I'm using the library over at https://github.com/stomp-php/stomp-php, and try to read messages from an Artemis queue. It's just a simple `$stomp->read();`.

## Expected behaviour:

- I get one message from the queue, or get told that there are no messages in the queue

## What is happening:

- The read method throws an exception (see below)
- When we don't connect using SSL, with a basic TCP connection, without a certificate, everything works perfectly fine. It happens only when we connect with the ssl scheme, the SSL port, with the certificate.

The exception is: `Was not possible to read data from stream.`, thrown in [stomp-php directory]/src/Network/Connection.php line 473.

Here is the context for the stream connection:

```
ssl:
  peer_name: '[censored]'
  cafile: '[censored certificate path].cer'
```

The certificate file exists and is read correctly (since when I change the path there's an exception thrown even before trying to send a message). The peer name is also correct, since another one triggers another error telling me that the peer name is incorrect.

My test is simple: I have a file that sends the messages, and a file that reads them. The sending always works when I don't subscribe to the queue. The reading is kinda messy.

**New information:** the reading seems to work when I remove 5 specific messages from the sending. That means if I send one of those 5, the reading throws the exception. If there are only the other messages but none of these 5, the reading works great. I would assume that the messages are in cause, but again, when I'm not connecting using SSL, everything works correctly.

**New information again:** every message that I have to not send in order to not have an error has a big amount of lines. I tried to send one of them again and remove every node but one from its content (XML): it worked correctly. So I tried with ~900 nodes: error. ~200 nodes: error. ~130 nodes: sometimes error. ~80 nodes: working.

SSL has troubles with large messages?

**New information again again:** I tried var_dumping the result of the fread call in the library. When the error occurs, the result is an empty string (''). From what I read in the doc, fread returns false on failure, and empty string on *timeout*. It would make sense with the "New information again" bloc, in which we discovered that large messages are causing the problem.

I tried stream_set_timeout() with 60 seconds, I tried to send a heartbeat manually, I tried setting it with the lib, I tried changing the timeouts with the lib and I tried increasing the maxReadBytes. Nothing worked so far. Still the same behaviour.

Comment: Can you provide your ActiveMQ Artemis configuration details? Were there any exceptions in the broker log?

Comment: I don't have access to that unfortunately :/

Comment: I edited the message, it's a lot different now. I noticed the error wasn't when I tried to send messages but when I tried to read what's in the queue.

Comment: Could you capture the incoming/outgoing STOMP frames? With that the behavior could potentially be reproduced in a unit test or something.

Comment: @JustinBertram There you go! https://pastebin.com/W3xAyJWR

Comment: Added information on how I test and new information about the bug in the description :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by reverting stomp-php library to version 4.3.1 :(